# What is this connector of a stepper motor?

Tags: connector, stepper-motor

I have a Vexta stepper motor in hand with very short wires. 
[image: Vexta motor]

As much as I want to recrimp a cable, or directly buy a replacement for it, I couldn't find the connector type. It has 0.1" pitch and a lock to hold the cable in place.
[image: The connector][image: Side View][image: Back view]

**What is its connector type?**

Comment: Plug, header , ( or wire to board connector) female 6 pin 0.1" pitch crimp, keyed with interlock, Mfg= ? try Molex and JST, source: Mouse , Digikey RS , others

Comment: Interlock is proprietary and may be OEM only  


Product > Housing,Wafer and Terminal >  2.54mm  TYPE BOARD TO WIRE, interlock  .. you can get without interlock too, but then not keyed for correct orientation.

Comment: Use a std connector and wire splices to existing connector and be sure to include Ferrite torroid or clam-shell for EMI and use twisted 3 wire for each phase.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I have a bunch of these steppers, all with short wires. Soldering other wires is a good option except when you have repeat the work for every single one. I would try to contact the Mfg.

Comment: Semi-Automated crimp connectors can be outsourced to cable mfg companies to adapt to a more common connector as well. You supply the material. They crimp it or they supply mat'l and labor  with your cables. Get a few quotes.

Answer (score 2):

My [Identiconn](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_2p5&s=Mini-Lock) tells me it's a [Molex Mini-lock](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/minilock), which you can buy [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0511030600/697857).

[image: Molex 0511030600]

{DigiKey}

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a 6 pin connector wire harness originally made by OEM. Please see attached.

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/6-pin-connector-wire-harness-in18AWG_60562115573.html

Comment: interlock may be a mismatch, best bet is source directly from OEM.  Oriental Motor Co.

Comment: Link is dead... which just goes to show why you show include details and photos (if any) from the link in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction is that it looks like a series from JST.  It's probably a Chinese knockoff of the JST line, but you'll have a hard time finding that, and then getting any real data if you do.

Comment: Concur that it looks like a JST part, could also be Molex.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  Does anyone that it's NOT a JST part?  I was only trying to point the OP in one possible direction, that from my experience, might be worth looking into.

Comment: It does look almost like JST [XA](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eXA1.pdf) series, doesn't it?